# Reactive bar plot with different datasets in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, bar-chart, shinydashboard

I have two data frames, "uno" and "dos" and I want to make a reactive bar plot considering the variables "tipo" and "fecha", i.e., I want to display the bar plot with data frame "uno" and group by "tipo" or "fecha", then do the same with data frame "dos". I can display a bar plot grouping only by one variable, but I don't know how to do it with more than one. I'm new in shiny so it's a little difficult for me to understand completlely the code's logic. I hope you can help me, thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)


uno <- data.frame(id = rnorm(10, 0, 1), 
                  tipo = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a"),
                  fecha = c(12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16))
dos <- data.frame(id = rnorm(10, 0, 1), 
                  tipo = c("c", "a", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a"),
                  fecha = c(11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16))
datafiles <- list(uno, dos)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', choices = c("uno" = "1", "dos" = "2")),
  plotOutput('graph')
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  outVar <- reactive({
    temp <- datafiles[[as.numeric(input$dataset)]]
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(outVar(), aes(fecha)) + geom_bar()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: What you mean by grouping? You can e.g. map `tipo` on fill which will give you a stacked bar plot or your can use facetting i.e. facet_wrap(~tipo) or .... Anyway in my opinion your issue is not a shiny related issue.

Comment: @stefan, by grouping I mean make a bar plot with tipo in the x axis and the num of observations in y axis. So I want the option to use any of both tipo and fecha in the x axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe then this is what you are looking for. You can add a second selectInput to select the variable and map this input on `x` in your call to `ggplot`. As the input is a character you have to make use of e.g. the `.data` pronoun:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)


uno <- data.frame(id = rnorm(10, 0, 1), 
                  tipo = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a"),
                  fecha = c(12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16))
dos <- data.frame(id = rnorm(10, 0, 1), 
                  tipo = c("c", "a", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a"),
                  fecha = c(11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16))
datafiles <- list(uno, dos)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', choices = c("uno" = "1", "dos" = "2")),
  selectInput('var', 'Choose Variable', choices = c("tipo", "fecha"), selected = "fecha"),
  plotOutput('graph')
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  outVar <- reactive({
    temp <- datafiles[[as.numeric(input$dataset)]]
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(outVar(), aes(.data[[input$var]])) + geom_bar()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```